# Convert Promise to async

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am trying to convert mySQL connection from promise to asycn await so far I have the following setup:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  password: "",
  user: "root",
  database: "usersdb",
  host: "localhost",
  port: "3306",
});

let usersDB = {};

usersDB.all = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.query("SELECT * FROM users", (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }

      return resolve(results);
    });
  });
};

usersDB.one = (id) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", [id], (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }

      return resolve(results[0]);
    });
  });
};

module.exports = usersDB;
```

Is there a way to convert this codes:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.query("SELECT * FROM users", (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }

      return resolve(results);
    });
```

to async await and make the code more compress or succint?

UPDATE: on my router, I have these codes:

```
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let results = await db.all();
    res.json(results);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});

router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let results = await db.one(req.params.id);
    res.json(results);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

So it just fine calling async await twice?

Comment: It would be easier to use a library that has a promise interface, such as `promise-mysql` or `mysql2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert any callback function to promise by using `util.promisify`

```
const util = require('util')
// ....
const query = util.promisify(pool.query)



// ... inside some async function
const users = await query("SELECT * FROM users;")


// or promise style
query("SELECT * FROM users;")
   .then((users) => {
      console.log(users)
    })
    .catch(console.error)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
usersDB.one = (id) => {
    try {
        const users = pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", [id]);
        return users;
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
};
```

Or more simply,

```
usersDB.one = (id) => pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", [id]);
```

Comment: But all of this is assuming the OP's mysql client even has a promise interface. The error "await' has no effect on the type of this expression.ts(80007)" would suggest that it hasn't, which is why my very first comment said that probably the whole promise stuff is meaningless until the OP changes to a client which even has a promise interface at all!

Comment: I cannot make edits because it would change the whole meaning of the answer, it should be "use another library, like `promise-mysql`" in my opinion. From the start I was trying to explain that the await wasn't the issue but the fact that pool.query doesn't even return a promise is what caused the TS warning...

Comment: but this library "mysql" also has promise (see: https://www.tabnine.com/code/javascript/functions/mysql/Pool/query?snippet=5f61bedf43564f2b5cc08217)

Comment: No, the code you linked first manually promisifies the function: https://github.com/antoniosarosi/Contacts-App-Nodejs/blob/91d96590458fcd9eaaf36592d88c20fe1a28e211/src/database.js#L16 - which is also a solution but I wouldn't recommend it because other functions still won't use promises and it's easy to forget that this is what's happening, it's better to use something that's designed for promises from the start.

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do is to promisify the DB call. You can acheive this by factorisation :

```js
const mysql = require("mysql");

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  password: "",
  user: "root",
  database: "usersdb",
  host: "localhost",
  port: "3306",
});

function promisify(...args){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.query(...args, (err, result) => {
            if(err) reject(err);
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}

let usersDB = {};

//Then you can call it this way : 

usersDB.all = async () => {
    return await promisify("SELECT * FROM users");
   //Note that you can avoid to await there.
};

usersDB.one = async (id) => {
    return await promisify("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", [id]);
};

module.exports = usersDB;
```